# Creating build of my project but Failed. React native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

In my expo project I am getting below error - 
Getting error -

> ```
> [stderr] * What went wrong:
> [stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProdMinSdkProdKernelReleaseResources'.
> [stderr] > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
> ```
>
> check logs for details
>       [stderr] * Try:
>       [stderr] Run with 
>       [stderr] --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>       [stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>       [stderr] BUILD FAILED in 6m 45s
>           690 actionable tasks: 690 executed
>           Error: Process exited with non-zero code: 1
>           at ChildProcess.child.on (/app/node_modules/xdl/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:39:21)
>           at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>           at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
>           at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
>           at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)

app.json

```
{
  "expo":{
    "name":"YYY",
    "slug":"YYY",
    "scheme":"yyy",
    "sdkVersion":"31.0.0",
    "icon":"./assets/icon.png",
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "platforms":[
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "orientation":"portrait",
    "primaryColor":"#cccccc",
    "packagerOpts":{
      "assetExts":[
        "ttf"
      ]
    },
    "android":{
      "package":"com.xxyy.xxyy",
      "splash":{
        "backgroundColor":"#ffffff",
        "ldpi":"./assets/splash.png",
        "mdpi":"./assets/mdpi/splash.png",
        "hdpi":"./assets/hdpi/splash.png",
        "xhdpi":"./assets/xhdpi/splash.png",
        "xxhdpi":"./assets/xxhdpi/splash.png",
        "xxxhdpi":"./assets/xxxhdpi/splash.png",
        "resizeMode":"cover"
      }
    },
    "ios":{
      "bundleIdentifier":"com.xxy.yyz",
      "splash":{
        "backgroundColor":"#ffffff",
        "resizeMode":"cover",
        "image":"./assets/ios/splash@2x.png",
        "tabletImage":"./assets/ios/splash.png"
      }
    },
    "androidStatusBarColor":"#334393",
    "androidStatusBar":{
      "barStyle":"light-content",
      "backgroundColor":"#334393"
    },
    "description":""
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the gradle build log? It should contain the message.

Comment: Resolved - https://forums.expo.io/t/creating-build-of-my-project-but-failed/20427/4